# Find group number for a given number from groups of increasing size

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I want to find out the group number for a given number from an ever increasing group size. Initial group size is 3.

```
Number     Group
1          1
2          1
3          1
4          2
5          2
6          2
7          2
8          3
9          3
10         3
11         3
12         3
13         4
14         4
15         4
16         4
. . .
```

I know I can use a loop to find this. But Is there is a formula which I can use to find Group number directly for a given number?

I used $\lfloor\frac{n + 2}{3}\rfloor$, but it only returns the group of fixed size 3.

Comment: What is a group number?  I thought at first you meant the number of non-isomorphic groups of order $n$, but there are $5$ groups of order $8$, not $3$.

Comment: @lulu I suspect OP doesn't mean groups in the algebraic sense. I could be wrong... (but retagged based on this suspicion)

Comment: For example 1, 2 ,3 numbers have one group i.e. 1. Similarly next 4 number 4, 5, 6, 7 have one group i.e. 2 as shown in the table. I hope I answered your question @lulu. I am sorry that I am bit unsure about the exact mathematical terms. The group size is ever increasing

Comment: @GurV Is this a correct interpretation of the question: I think we're putting numbers $1, 2, \ldots n$ into sets: The first $3$ in a set of size $3$, the next $4$ into a set of size $4$, the next $5$ into a set of size $5$, and so on. I think the question can be stated as, "How many sets are there, if we've put the first $n$ numbers into sets in this fashion?"

Comment: @pjs36 - Exactly yes. But I want to find out which set a given number belongs to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest number in group $n$ is the sum of $n$ terms of $3+4+5+\ldots$.  We write that as $\sum_{i=1}^n (i+2)=\frac 12n(n+1)+2n=\frac 12(n^2+5n)$.  If you were given a number $k$ that was guaranteed to be the largest one in a group, you could solve $k=\frac 12(n^2+5n)$ or $n^2+5n-2k=0$ with the quadratic formula to get $n=\frac 12(-5+\sqrt{25+8k})$ where we have taken the plus sign so the result is positive.  Even if your $k$ is not the last in a group, you can use this formula and round up to the next whole number.  For example, if we are given $k=15,$ we say $n=\lceil\frac 12(-5+\sqrt{25+8 \cdot 15})\rceil=\lceil\frac 12(-5+\sqrt{145})\rceil\approx \frac 12(7.04)\rceil=\lceil3.52\rceil=4$

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks Ross :-)

Comment: I just had to do a little fixing in the formula you provided to make it work for my case - It's in python - `int((-5 + math.sqrt(25 + 8 * n - 2)) / 2) + 1` as the group number was off by one and off by one position.

Comment: I think your $+1$ is replacing my ceiling because you are taking the floor by an int() but that will fail for the last number of a group.  The $-2$ is then a kludge to fix the last number of a group.  I believe it will work that way.  I believe Python gives an integer square root when it is available so you don't have to worry about numeric precision in the formula.  The kludge would offend me and I think a proper ceiling function is available in math.

Comment: You are absolutely right. When I used `math.ceil((-5 + math.sqrt(25 + 8 * n)) / 2)` it works perfectly. Thanks for the answer and explanation once again.